# Java REST Api (running on tomcat) - easiest way to get real-time synchronization between client and Server

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, backbone.js, real-time

I wanted to achieve real-time synchronization between my clients and my server without Ajax Interval pulling. So here is my setup:

Frontend: Backbone
API: Java REST Api (GET/PUT/POST)
Database: MySQL

So this is how my webapp works right now:

1. Ajax Request to API ->
2. API retrieves information from Database ->
3. API forms a model out of the response from MySQL ->
4. API sends response to Client (Frontend)

This is a really basic setup with **Ajax Get/Post** requests.

The **API** has about **25k** lines of code. And we are now thinking about real-time synchronization between Client and Backend. 
What do you think, could be an easy way for me? 
(I don't expect very detailed answers - my question was not detailed :) Would be just cool if you can point me in some good directions and new technologies).

Also it would be interesting to hear if some of you did a rewrite of their API in order to achieve *real-time synchronization* and tell me about the benefits for their customers :)

EDIT:

Well i tried to find out, which technology suites better to my application - SSE or WebSockets. I didn't find any new postings about this (only postings 2-3 years ago).
So the usecase for "real-time" would be something like a twitter-feed. For me, SSE seems like the perfect candidate. WebSockets would be very complicated - think about scaling with Websockets (Pusher maybe). So what do you think fits better for a "real-time" feed - SSE or Websockets? (it doesn't matter if there is a lag of 2-3 seconds till the update comes to the client)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use webSocket API. For example it is available in Sails based on node.js
There is also a java EE websocket implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does it make sense to mix a REST API with webSocket? Or is it maybe better to just write a new API? (Of course - really difficult to answer. But i'm at that point just interested in different opinions :))

Comment: You should try to reuse what's already there as much as possible, if the business permits. Don't reinvent the wheel. The best bet would be an open source framework where you could adopt what doesn't fit your needs. Yes it makes sense, they are actually complementary.

Comment: I just read about Server-Side-Events. That seems like a pretty good solution, if you don't want to burry your old API and build a new one. SSE just holds a connection between client and server - if there is an update the client can react depending on the update. The only problem i identified with that solution is, that the database gets a pretty high load. 
What do you think about SSE?

Comment: It is actually called Server-sent events. You should handle DB load yourself. You could use some caching strategy. Good idea. Try it and see what's the load and then improve.

Comment: True. Server Sent Events. Thank you. That helped me a lot!